# While using google chrome whole systen locks up

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

It very random, can happen with 1 window and 4-8 tabs or just two windows but I guess when some sort of condition hits everything locks up. My mouse works perfectly, but I might as well be mousing around a picture. Nothing can be clicked, pressing the windows key on my keyboard does nothing and none of the kill commands work. Though strangely if I'm watching a video the image freezes but the audio keeps playing as if there is nothing wrong. The only thing I can do is either power cycle or  alt+sysreq+REISUB.

I am using ubuntu 14.04

AMD black edition II processor

gigabyte motherboard

panda wireless nob

nvidia gtx 650

If you need the specific model of the board and processor I can look them up but I don't remember off the top of my head.

Is this an issue with Chrome, ubuntu or something in my hardware?

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: How often does this happen? Do you always have video playing while this happens, or did it happen also without having used video? Can you test whether the same happens if you use Firefox instead of Chrome?

Comment: I think I tried installing nvidia drivers but I don't remember if it worked or not. Yes, I usually do have a video running. I actually tried using Firefox after posting this/reisubbing again and have had not issues at all.